# pyspark matplotlib integration with Zeppelin

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to draw histogram using pyspark in Zeppelin notebook. Here is what I have tried so far,

```
%pyspark

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
...
x=dateDF.toPandas()["year(CAST(_c0 AS DATE))"].values.tolist()
y=dateDF.toPandas()["count(year(CAST(_c0 AS DATE)))"].values.tolist()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This code run without no errors but this does not give the expected plot. So I googled and found this [documantation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#matplotlib-integration-pyspark),
[image]

According to this, I tried to enable angular flag as follows,

```
x=dateDF.toPandas()["year(CAST(_c0 AS DATE))"].values.tolist()
y=dateDF.toPandas()["count(year(CAST(_c0 AS DATE)))"].values.tolist()
plt.close()
z.configure_mpl(angular=True,close=False)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

But now I'm getting an error called `No module named 'mpl_config'` and I have no idea how to enable angular without this. If you can suggest how to resolve this it will be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Zeppelin 0.10.0 I was able to plot a matplotlib plot as simply as this in a `%pyspark` interpreter:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = list(range(10))
y = list(map(lambda x: x*25, x))

plt.close()  # Close any existing plot when re-running this paragraph.
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=20)
plt.grid()
plt.title('Inline plotting example', fontsize=20)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Output in Zeppelin:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After struggling some time I noticed that this is a major [Bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3873) on Zepplien notebook marked in 2020 November by @Ruslan Dautkhanov. According to him,

> mpl_config is part of core Zeppelin.
> The old Python Interpreter was copying it manually here
> https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/0d746fa2e2787a661db70d74035120ae3516ace3/python/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/python/PythonInterpreter.java#L179

**But new IPythonInterpeter doesn't do this.**

I hope this will solve in future and keep the question for future references

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you resolve it?

Comment: @SimranSingh I used jupyter notebook and did the plotting part